# Angular nvd3 donut chart - how to add a static or dynamic title? -

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using angular  nvd3-pie-chart. Any idea or suggestion how to add a static or dynamic title at the center of the donut chart?

Here is the code block.

```
 <nvd3-pie-chart 
    data="exampleData" id="exampleId" showLabels="true" x="xFunction()" y="yFunction()" donut="true" donutRatio=".5" donutLabelsOutside="true">

</nvd3-pie-chart>

function ExampleCtrl($scope){
            $scope.exampleData = [
                {
                    key: "One",
                    y: 5
                },
                {
                    key: "Two",
                    y: 2
                }
            ];

            $scope.xFunction = function(){
                return function(d) {
                    return d.key;
                };
            }
            $scope.yFunction = function(){
                return function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                };
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try to prepare plunker or fiddle, you might get answer sooner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use below:

```
title: {
enable: true,
text: 'Chart Title'
}
```

Refer to below link:
[NVD3 Docs](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/blob/gh-pages/js/lineChart.js)

Comment: Thank you Ritesh for your help.